# "It does not meet our quality standards" <--- huh? Seriously?

Tags: support, question-quality

I just tried submitting this question:

> #### 64-bit Executable Packer
>
> Is there a good, free packer out there for 64-bit executables?
>
> I'm looking for something like UPX, except that UPX doesn't seem to support 64-bit executables...

and got the "it doesn't meet our quality standards" error.

...wtf? Is it really ***that*** bad? (Is it bad at all?)

Comment: Did something just get changed, or was I hallucinating? I just [submitted the same thing and it worked](http://superuser.com/questions/293414/64-bit-executable-packer)...

Comment: This question seems reasonable, to the point, and easy to understand.  It also includes some helpful clarification immediately after the question.  It certainly meets _my_ quality standards.

Comment: Are there any ... What is a ... How can I use a ... or even Why can't I ask questions about ... would be a **real** question.

Comment: @Ivo: Huh? confused

Comment: Your original 'question' was "64-bit Executable Packer". My point was that phrasing it as a Jeopardy-styled question, it actually makes more sense what the heck you mean. Like Jeff said: 3 words is just too short to be a useful title.

Comment: @Ivo: Eh... I disagree. :\ I think the title was fine and succinct.

Comment: maybe the person who flagged it doesn't know what a 'packer' is.  there are 10,000 different specialty areas in IT/tech and not all involve software development.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's too short. Particularly the title, but .. in general.

Comment: It's kind of hard to add anything else to it, unless I start going into details about what a packer *is* (in which case, the person reading it probably won't have the answer anyway). But see my comment on my question... apparently it now worked for some reason. Did something change?

Comment: @mehr yes, something changed. Compare, and read the words *particularly* in the above post.

Comment: @Jeff: I do realize you're referring to the ellipses (right? unless I'm missing it), but the thing is, I also tried it *without* the ellipses before posting here, and it *still* told me it's not valid...

Comment: @mehr I think you're missing something obvious here. Compare the above question content with what actually got posted.

Comment: @Jeff: The only differences I see are (1) the ellipses, and (2) the title, which was actually a later fix by @Sathya, not what I managed to post... am I missing something?

Comment: @mehr ahh, I missed the title edit. Well, ellipses it is then. But your title was ridiculously short.

Comment: @Jeff: Okay... though like I said, it wasn't the ellipses either, because I already tried that before posting this on meta. :\ Is the algorithm nondeterministic?

Answer (score 2):

What were the tags selected? It's not bad, but then again, the q[uestion filter is algorithmic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/133693), rather than manual filter. Try adding more details about what Executable packer does.

Comment: I think they were `executable`, `packer`, and `windows`. I do realize it's algorithmic (hence why I marked it as a bug :P); I'll try adding something else, but I really think it might cause more inconvenience for people than realized.

Comment: executible, packer.. hmm what about the OS? I know executibles & packing in general refer to Windows but you really should add them.

Comment: Yeah I originally had it, I just forgot about the tag here when you asked me. :)